# Who is my best friend?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

It's that time of the month again,
For my best friend
And I feel slightly apprehensive.

I'm not sure whether this is all part of nature's Grand Scheme Of Things
My other friend, Dodge,
Thinks that this is all extremely hilarious,
and proceeds in telling us so as he catches the sun in his outstretched palms.

One of us is a traitor, he's not
extra sharp,
and he can't tell that we are the good guys.

But I guess that
disposing of him isn't exactly what Dodge would like$\ldots$
It's that time of the month again$\ldots$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Remus Lupin, being the friend that Sirius is apprehensive about

Being a

> Werewolf, he changes at the full moon, which comes once a month

Dodge, I think, is

> James, maybe the reference to quidditch(the sun part) and Dodge from him being an illegal Animagus, a stag, which is the symbol of Dodge, the car company

The traitor is, of course,

> The idiot Peter Pettigrew

And since

> Harry didn't kill Pettigrew because he thought that James wouldn't like it, that fits the part about Dodger not wanting to dispose of him.

Comment: @GracelynRioux Happy now?

Comment: I ninja'd you! :-) But +1 since you were so close.

Comment: Arghhh.  Wait, ninjas?

Comment: It asks for the best friend rather than the narrator, does it not?  But +1 for getting the snitch part first time round

Comment: RL as SB's best friend seems a bit off to me, so I put JP as best friend (although obviously RL is the friend referred to in the 2nd line).

Comment: Well, we'll just have to wait a bit

Answer (score 3):

Credit to AJL for the general theme of the answer, but the narrator is

> Sirius Black,

making the answer to the title

> James Potter.

*It's that time of the month again,*

> Full moon.

*For my best friend*

> Remus Lupin.

*And I feel slightly apprehensive.*

> Well, wouldn't you if you had a friend who was a werewolf?

*I'm not sure whether this is all part of nature's Grand Scheme Of Things*

> Werewolves are unnatural.

*My other friend, Dodge,*

> James Potter.

*Thinks that this is all extremely hilarious,*

> That was his personality: have a laugh about everything.

*and proceeds in telling us so as he catches the sun in his out stretched palms.*

> The Golden Snitch.

*One of us is a traitor, he's not

extra sharp,*

> Peter Pettigrew.

*and he can't tell that we are the good guys.*

> He picked the wrong side.

*But I guess that 

disposing of him isn't exactly what Dodge would like…*

> James was sort of fond of Peter.

*It's that time of the month again...*

> Full moon.